# Current sources in parallel

Tags: amplifier, current-source

[image]

I don't know enough about the behavior of real current sources and negative feedback amplifiers to answer a question that recently came up.

If two ideal current sources are connected in parallel as shown in the diagram above then the resulting current at point A will be the sum of the currents supplied by each ideal source. Many real current sources have negative feedback circuits which are designed to provide approximate ideal sources. If the sources are of slightly different frequencies (say 2000 and 2010 Hz) can the negative feedback circuit produce an amplified difference frequency (10 Hz in this example) in the current measured at point A?

Comment: Frequency of... what?

Comment: The instantaneous currents will add. You can do a simple simulation in excel.

Answer (score 0):

The sources shown appear to be DC sources. They add. Simple.

If you connect current sources in parallel they should behave reasonably well, provided that you do not go outside the compliance range that all real sources have. For example, the source may be able to provide 5A provided the voltage across the terminals is in the range of 0 to 10V. Real sources will also have a non-infinite output impedance and may have trouble tracking fast changes in the output voltage.

This is analogous to voltage sources in series, which is typically not a problem if the sources are isolated from each other (and you don't exceed the maximum current of either supply). The voltage sources will not have zero output impedance and may have trouble tracking fast changes in the output current.

If you are driving two bipolar AC current sources in parallel with different frequencies then there could certainly be additional errors as a result, depending on the design of the circuits. Many current sources are unipolar only- it's more complex to make a bipolar source and is often not required. Keep in mind that typically current sources are derived from a voltage source (or sources in the case of a bipolar source).

Comment: Yes, the diagram shows DC currents. I wanted a pic to go with the question and, of course, I mentioned that they are meant to be AC in the text of the question. I wish a I had more information about the type, model, and manufacture of the current source. That will obviously matter. My question arises due to some questions I have about methods used in a recent journal article in which two sinusoidal current sources are applied in parallel.

Comment: @D_J_S Ideally there would be no problem and they should behave decently (for example, the stability should not be compromised if both are stable to begin with). If the load is weird in some way you might get weird transients.

Comment: @immibis  yes, that's why the answer addresses a number of non-ideal behaviors- finite output impedance, stability and compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Current Sources often are sense-feedback circuits. If that "sense" is remote from the actual high-compliance output (e.g. a cascade FET or bipolar or tube is the intermediary), you are OK.

On the other hand, if the two regulatory circuits interact, e.g. if either gets pulled out of its compliance region, expect issues.

Comment: analogsystemsrf. Yes. That (source interaction) is the sort of behavior that concerns me. Do you have a reference addressing such issues? I will try to contact the authors and ask what type of current source they used.

Comment: In integrated-circuit design (I've done a fair bit of that), we'll run current-sources in parallel, and depend on the output resistance (often set by Vearly for bipolars, or lambda effect for FETs) to maintain adequate isolation. You want to run 2 sinusoidal current sources in parallel. OK. To achieve precision, and achieve stability, the internal regulatory circuits need to be isolated from the summing node (the output). Thus cascade devices ---- FETs for accuracy, running  grounded gate---- after each of the 2 current sources and into the "load", is a solution.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a bit more description about the physics of your proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZDoUL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hi, analogsystemsrf. Excuse my ignorance please. Would you tell me how the FETs help achieve isolation of the sources? Thanks!